# Multiple listview inside scroll view getview metod called twice in adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I have 5 list view inside scroll view ..list view displayed according to specific condition.. the major problem is getview  method called twice..for example sizeof the data 1 means ,getview method called 2 times..so the additional view get created..i set the heigth of listview to fill parent but not works..i give the my adaper class and view

```
@Override
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent) {

    Log.e("Count++++",getCount()+"");

  //  View superView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);


    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {


        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.checkbox_adapter, null);


        final  ViewHolder_check holder = new ViewHolder_check();
        System.out.println(boxx+":::");

        if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("checkbox")) {
            // String customName = getItem(position);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_checkbox);;
            holder.check_box_txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_box_txt);
            holder.set=holder.check_box_txt.getText().toString();
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            if(!ProductDetailView.checkboxView.contains(holder.checkBox))

            ProductDetailView.checkboxView.add(holder.checkBox);

            holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    String response;
                    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();

                    if(holder.checkBox.isChecked())
                    {
                        arrayset.add(ProductDetailView.checkboxop.get(position).getOptionTypeId());

                        arrayset_option.add(ProductDetailView.checkboxop.get(position).getOptionId());


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arrayset_option.remove(ProductDetailView.checkboxop.get(position).getOptionId());
                        arrayset.remove(ProductDetailView.checkboxop.get(position).getOptionTypeId());
                    }

                    Log.e("arraysetption",arrayset_option+"");

                    Log.e("arrayset",arrayset+"");
                    ArrayList<String> vauecontains=new ArrayList<String>();

                    ProductDetailView.mainvalues=new JSONArray();
                    for(int i=0;i<arrayset_option.size();i++)
                    {
                        String check=arrayset_option.get(i).toString();
                        JSONArray optinidvalues=new JSONArray();
                        if(vauecontains.contains(check))
                        {

                        }
                        else
                        {

                            for(int j=0;j<arrayset_option.size();j++)
                            {
                                if(check.equalsIgnoreCase(arrayset_option.get(j).toString()))
                                {

                                    Log.e("true", "true"+check);
                                    vauecontains.add(check);
                                    optinidvalues.put(arrayset.get(j).toString());

                                    // break;
                                }
                            }

                            try {
                                JSONObject obj1=new JSONObject();
                                obj1.put(check,optinidvalues);
                                ProductDetailView.mainvalues.put(obj1);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Log.e("mainvalues",ProductDetailView.mainvalues+"");

                        }


                    }

                    //Log.e("json", ProductDetailView.main_json+"sett");
                    ProductDetailView.checkPosition=position;
                }
            });

        }
        if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("radio")) {
            holder.custom_radiobox = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.custom_radiobox);;
            holder.check_box_txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_box_txt);
            holder.custom_radiobox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.custom_radiobox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Log.e("check", "inside" + holder.check_box_txt.getText().toString() + "kk" + position);
                    ProductDetailView.radioPosition = position;

                    if (imageref != null) {
                        imageref.setImageResource(R.drawable.option_btn_deselected1);
                    }
                    holder.custom_radiobox.setImageResource(R.drawable.option_btn_selected1);

                    imageref = holder.custom_radiobox;

                }
            });

        }


        if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("date")) {
            holder.dateView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.datepicker);;
            holder.dateView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.dateView.setText("Pick Delivery Date");
            holder.check_box_txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_box_txt);
            holder.check_box_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           // holder.dateView.setId(editTag);
           // editTag++;

            if(!ProductDetailView.dateView.contains(holder.dateView)) {
                ProductDetailView.dateView.add(holder.dateView);
            }
            Log.e("errormssg","dateviewcalled:::"+ProductDetailView.dateView+"id"+holder.dateView.getText()+"size"+values.size());
            holder.dateView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    String date=  showAlerttime("Date",view);


                    //holder.dateView.setText(date);
                }
            });



        }

        if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("time")) {
            holder.timepicker = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
            holder.timepicker.setText("Pick Delivery Time");
            holder.timepicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.check_box_txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_box_txt);
            holder.check_box_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(!ProductDetailView.timeView.contains(holder.timepicker))
            ProductDetailView.timeView.add(holder.timepicker);

            holder.timepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    String date=  showAlerttime("Time",view);
                    //holder.timepicker.setText(date);
                }
            });

        }
        if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("datetime")) {
            holder.date_timepicker = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date_timepicker);
            holder.date_timepicker.setText("Pick Delivery Date and Time");
            holder.date_timepicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.check_box_txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_box_txt);
            holder.check_box_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(!ProductDetailView.datetimeView.contains(holder.date_timepicker))
            ProductDetailView.datetimeView.add(holder.date_timepicker);
            holder.date_timepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    String date= showAlerttime("Date and Time",view);
                    //holder.date_timepicker.setText(date);
                }
            });


        }

        if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
            holder.customntext = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.customntext);
            //holder.customntext.setText(");
            holder.customntext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.check_box_txt=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.check_box_txt);
            holder.check_box_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.customntext.setId(editTag);
            if(!ProductDetailView.editText.contains(holder.customntext))
            ProductDetailView.editText.add(holder.customntext);
            editTag++;



        }
        v.setTag(holder);

    }

    System.out.println(boxx+":::");

    if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("checkbox")) {

        String customName = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder_check holder = (ViewHolder_check) v.getTag();
        holder.check_box_txt.setText(customName);

    }
    if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("radio")) {

        String customName = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder_check holder = (ViewHolder_check) v.getTag();
        holder.check_box_txt.setText(customName);

    }
    if(boxx.equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
        ProductDetailView.text_values=new JSONArray();
        final ViewHolder_check holder = (ViewHolder_check) v.getTag();
        Log.e("sign", "edittextgetcalled");

    }



    return v;
}
```

This is how i set adapter

```
     if(isDatecustom)
                {
                    date_list.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    RelativeLayout date_list_lay = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.date_list_lay);
                    date_list_lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    CustomCheckboxAdapter checkboxAdapter = new CustomCheckboxAdapter(ProductDetailView.this, datevalues,0,"date");
                    date_list.setAdapter(checkboxAdapter);
                    setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(date_list);

                }
```

in xml page

```
     <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/drop_down_list_lay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center" >

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/drop_down_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:divider="@null"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

---

### **// method to set listview height**

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
    ListAdapter myListAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
    if (myListAdapter == null) {
        // do nothing return null
        return;
    }
    // set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
    int totalHeight = 0;
    for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {

        View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, listView);
        if (listItem instanceof ViewGroup)
            listItem.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) baseactivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        int screenWidth = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
        int height = display.getHeight(); // deprecated

        int listViewWidth = screenWidth - 10 - 10;
        int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listViewWidth,
                MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        listItem.measure(widthSpec, 0);

        totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    // setting listview item in adapter
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
    listView.requestLayout();
}
```

Comment: yes you are right...

Comment: Any way to fix this?

Comment: Its a bad practice to put list in a scroll view, you can customize your listview to have different rows instead. Also you are facing view recycling, you can handle this by checking convertView.  That is the counterpart to this statement: `if (v == null){ -- some code-- } else{ --some code to handle---}` Something like - `else { 
             holder = (ViewHolder_check)v.getTag(); 
         }`

Comment: datavalues have one item and view called twice

Comment: Just use vertical LinearLayouts instead...where to use this in code?